# How can I  customize the Devise gem for a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to use devise for my application and there are different user levels  i need to  edit User controller in devise plug-in

Comment: Let me introduce you to my friend, the period: http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2002/10/11/

Answer (score 1):

Are you handling all of the users in users controller?

if so...

before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:change_password],
                                     :except => [:create, :show, :show_profile, :signup]

You can mimic the same for admin user or any other type of user...
like

before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!, :only => [:edit, :update, :change_password],
                                     :except => [:new, :create, :show, :show_profile, :signup]

in which case you need to write the authenticate_user / authenticate_admin_user and handle your business logic in...

If your requirement is something else... plz let me know...